# Listening for Data coming to Web Service

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I have an Android Device and a Web Service. 
All I want is whenever Web Service *receives a data from other device*,my Android's app will know and notice a message or notification.

There is 2 ways I think can solve this problem,

1st. Web Service whenever receives a data, it will push a data,or message,or something through internet so Android app will be known . Is it impossible?

2nd. Android App will send a request to Web Service to method A,at WS's side,we use Async-Task to listen when data comes to method B,flag will be true and Async-Task will return String of content to Android's App.

Can somebody help me? Thank you guys !

Comment: are you talking about android push notifications?

Comment: Are the updates needed only when the user uses the App or even when the app is closed? the solution to this kind of requirement depends on the details.

Comment: ^Paul: No man,I want to whenever Webservice receives a data,it will let my Android app knows so I dont have to check the Web Service.

Comment: ^Udi Idan: I want to use Service or BroadCastReceiver to keep listening in the background. The important is I want my App knows right after WS receives data.

Comment: @Nguyen, that's what push notification are for. Why can't you use them?

Comment: @SimoneLeoni u mean WS will send a notification to android when it receives a data? I just start to learn WS so I don't know much about it.

Comment: It's not about WS in general, it's the best way to notify an android device without draining battery! You should definitely checkout GCMs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Gcm to receive notification on android device from server side.
Have a look: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Thank you,I will take a look and try it now.